# Regex to match url with blank space

Tags: regex

Basically I want to do a Match with a regex expression to get this:

```
/xpto/uuuu/That name tho [1080p].mp4
```

from

```
<section class="video">
        <video id="video" autoplay="">
            <source src="/xpto/uuuu/That name tho [1080p].mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
</section>
```

What i want is to get relative path that ends with .mp4 from big HTML page.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

SOLVED BY RAJ:

```
"(?<=src="")[^""]+"
```

Comment: unclear. Explain your question a bit more.

Comment: Hi Raj do you get it now?

Comment: try this `[^\/]+$` regex.

Comment: That is basic that one i already tried and doesn't work :(

Comment: What regex engine or implementation? What have you tried?

Comment: https://www.myregextester.com/index.php i'm using this website with the string that are in the main question, and try to get a match as described

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lookbehind to match all the characters which are just after to  `src="` and upto to the next `"` symbol.(ie, the value of source attribute),

```
(?<=src=")[^"]+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/12)